# Chaining Constructors in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, constructor

I try to save code and reduce failure rate for maintainability by reusing constructors as much as possible. Now, I came across a Situation, where I think I'll have to duplicate code, but maybe you know a solution.

```
public class Bar {
  public List<string> BarList {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public Bar() {
    this.BarList = new List<string>();
  }

  public Bar(XmlNode node)
    : this() {
    //create from xml
  }
}

public class Foo: Bar {
  public List<int> FooList {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  public Foo()
    : base() {
    this.FooList = new List<int>();
  }

  public Foo(XmlNode node)
    : base(node) {
    //create from enhanced xml
  }
}
```

Each constructor with XMLNode as parameter calls the parameterless constructor before for initialisation. But how to manage, that the derived class Foo calls its own parameterless constructor AND the the constructor with the XmlNode parameter of the base class?

The desired behaviour of constructor chain would be:

```
Foo(XmlNode)->Bar(XmlNode)->Foo()->Bar()
```

Comment: What would you like the desired behavior to be?  It's not clear to me

Comment: It's sufficient to call **just one** constructor to have object ... constructed. I think `base(node)` should call `base()` **already** if it's required.

Comment: Is the difference between Foo class and Bar class is only List<int> and List<string> (I hope not). If so Why not just have one class `Foo<T>{ List<T> FooList}`

Comment: There are lots of subtle variations on this issue. Choosing the best answer would depend on what you are doing in the Bar(XmlNode) constructor.

Comment: `Each constructor with XMLNode as parameter calls the parameterless constructor before for initialisation` - I don't see `Foo(XmlNode node)` calling `this()`.  Isn't this kind of thing usually handled with an internal private (or protected) `.Init()` method that can be used by all constructors?

Comment: Consider following option `Foo(XmlNode)->Bar(XmlNode)->FooMethod()->BarMethod()`, I repeat it should be sufficient to call just one constructor (which can call again only one base constructor, etc.) to construct instance. If you need to call more than one  - you are doing something wrong. Extract the code you want to call into methods = no problem with calling, but problem with how to initialize object (maybe inherited object forget to call base method = problems)..

Comment: Do you want both BarList and FooList (in this instance) to be initialised when either constructor is called? If so, how about initialising the respective lists in the BarList/FooList property (or use a private field) and use an optional parameter in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't abstract the work of the constructor?
Something like: [check new function init]

```
public class Foo : Bar
{
    public List<int> FooList
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public Foo()
      : base()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init() { this.FooList = new List<int>(); }

    public Foo(XmlNode node)
      : base(node)
    {
        Init();
        //create from enhanced xml
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want `Foo(XmlNode node)` to call `this()` and `base(node)`, which can't be done.

btw: `ctor() : base()` or in your case `Foo() : base()` is implicit.

Your only option here is a bit of code-redundancy.

E.g:

```
public class Foo: Bar {
    public List<int> FooList { get; private set; }

    public Foo() : base() {
        Initialize();
    }

    public Foo(XmlNode node) : base(node) {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected void Initialize() {
        this.FooList = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, what you're looking to do is not possible unless you abstract the behaviour out into a separate method.

An alternative, however, if you wanted to stick with constructors is to use optional parameters as follows:

```
public class Bar {
  public List<string> BarList {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public Bar(string xmlNode = null) {
    this.BarList = new List<string>();

    if (xmlNode != null) { 
        //create from xml 
    }
  }
}

public class Foo: Bar {
  public List<int> FooList {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  public Foo(string xmlNode = null)
  : base(xmlNode)
  {
    this.FooList = new List<int>();

    if (xmlNode != null) { 
        //create from enhanced xml 
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, the compromise here is now you have branching logic in the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason, why I chain constructors always the other way around (the parameterless calls ctor with one parameter, which calls ctor with two parameters, etc). The purpose of each constructor is just to provide a default value for the missing parameter and its body stays empty. All the work will then be done in the most specialized constructor, which calls the most specialized constructor of the base class. That way you always have only one implementation that needs to be maintained.

```
public abstract class Bar
{
    public List<string> BarList { get; private set; }

    public Bar()
        : this(null)
    { }

    public Bar(XmlNode node)
    {
        this.BarList = new List<string>();

        if (node == null)
            return;

        //create from xml
    }
}

public class Foo : Bar
{
    public List<int> FooList { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
        : this(null)
    { }

    public Foo(XmlNode node)
        : base(node)
    {
        this.FooList = new List<int>();

        if (node == null)
            return;

        //create from enhanced xml
    }
}
```